# Reindex Solr in crafter delivey version 3

Tags: crafter-cms

I am trying to reindex solr in one of our crafter delivery node with curl command

curl "http://{hostname}:{port}/api/1/target/deploy/{environment}/{siteName}" -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/json" -d '{ "reprocess_all_files": true }'

And changing the curl command URL as per our configuration but I am getting an error "{"message":"Content type 'text/json;charset=UTF-8' not supported"}"

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The content type seems to be wrong, it should be `application/json`, not `text/json`. The documentation seems to have an error.